# cap deploy - getting permission denied

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, capistrano, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my rails project into sub-domain, but I am getting following error while running  **cap deploy**

```
 [Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.
 * 2013-09-27 21:14:44 executing `deploy'
 * 2013-09-27 21:14:44 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
 * 2013-09-27 21:14:44 executing `deploy:update_code'
executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:anveshnarepo/techzoo.git master"
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
 * executing "rm -rf /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu/releases/20130927154447; true"
servers: ["http://anveshnatech.com/edupdu/www"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: http://anveshnatech.com/edupdu/www (SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
 Command git ls-remote git@github.com:anveshnarepo/techzoo.git master returned status code pid 12392 exit 128
```

If i am trying to run **cap deploy:setup** it is displaying something like:

```
[Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.
* 2013-09-27 21:23:57 executing `deploy:setup'
* executing "mkdir -p /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu     /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu/releases    /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu/shared /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu/shared/system /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu/shared/log /var/www/anveshnatech.com/public_html/edupdu/shared/pids"
servers: ["http://anveshnatech.com/edupdu/www"]
connection failed for: http://anveshnatech.com/edupdu/www (SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One error is that you defined a URI where host should go. I suspect you have

```
role :app, "http://anveshnatech.com/edupdu/www"
```

in your capfile, when you need something like:

```
role :app, "anveshnatech.com"
```

or (example)

```
role :app, "10.1.1.1"
```

These are probably not be the only errors, you have some permission problems with your git key and some strangeness with deprecation warnings.